# Does javascript ValidatorEnable still supports in ASP.Net 4.0?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, asp.net-4.0

I would like to disable a `RequireFieldValidator` control by a certain condition.

I have tried this code

```
function doSomething()
{
  var myVal = document.getElementById('RequiredFieldValidator1');
  ValidatorEnable(myVal, false); 
}
```

The result is, this function make the validation message disappear but the validation still fire when we post-back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for bothering, i have just found the solution to my own question. This code is truly disable the client-side validator but i still need to set the disable post-back validator on my own page by the following code.

```
public override void Validate()
{

    RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = !RadioButton1.Checked;
    // Now perform validation
    base.Validate();
}
```